How acceptable is it for cryptic clues to be time sensitive/based on current events?
Take for example, this clue:

Base 8, which is not drunk, lost 'als', and became this month. (7)

Where the solution would be:

 "octal" + "sober" - "als" = "october". The definition is "this month", which would only work during October.

Would this be acceptable? What about if "this month" was part of the wordplay instead, indicating October (this month)?

Another example could be:

Paper from book, with 'r', becomes Lebanese explosive. (5)

Where the solution would be:

 "page" + "r" = "pager". The definition is "Lebanese explosive", which would only make sense after those pagers exploded in Lebanon.

Would this be acceptable? And also what if "Lebanese explosive" was part of the wordplay instead, indicating pager (one of the things that were detonated in Lebanon)?


How acceptable would these clues be?

It might depend on where the puzzle is published. And there used to be frequent crossword clues which used 'di' (the late Princess Diana) but not so much now.

Should this be on meta?

@Lucenaposition No, this is a question about cryptic clues, not about how to make a puzzle involving them on this site.
